# Java Profiling - VisualVM

Tags: java, jmx, visualvm

I invoke my Java application with different arguments from a shell script. Each time it binds to a different port. I am trying to use VisualVM to profile my application, but since it uses different ports for each invocation, I have to manually connect to the application every time from VisualVM GUI. Is there a way to do it more efficient?

Comment: Do what more efficiently? VisualVM is a manual profiler, you choose which program(s) to profile and then profile cpu or heap (or just monitor the program from the graphs).

Answer (score 0):

You can always setup JMX for your app by setting System properties at startup:

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1234\
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
    YourJavaApplication
```

Then you'll be able to store a profile in jvisualvm for connecting to that specific JMX port.

Comment: I tried this, but I get the already bind exception on the same port.

Comment: One port per app... are you on windows or linux? Choosing free protected ports < 1024) makes sure they are not assigned dynamically